# Gradle Build is failing on increasing versionCode in Android Studio

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have a published app on Google Play Store, now I want to fix some bugs and release an update of the same app on Play Store. I tried changing the `versionCode` to `2` from `1` and `versionName` to `1.1` from `1.0` but I am getting an exception

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'F:\Resume-Guide\app\build.gradle' line: 12

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Could not find method versionCode() for arguments [1.0] on DefaultConfig_Decorated{name=main, 
dimension=null, minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=22, mCodename='null'}, 
targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=28, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=null, 
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, 
renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null, 
applicationId=com.finale.resumeguide, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, 
testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, 
signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], 
mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}, mWearAppUnbundled=null} of type 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.
```

app level `buid.gradle` looks like this -

```
...
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.finale.resumeguide"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 2
    versionName '1.1'

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
...
```

Please help me out. I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: can you please share the app gradle file?

Comment: @JassemBenHamida I have already shared in the question

Comment: Is it all you have changed?

Comment: @CoolMind yes I just changed versionCode and versionName

Comment: Try to invalidate caches, then rebuild. Also maybe you should delete `build` folders (before invalidate).

Comment: @CoolMind I don't understand what you mean by invalidate cache. Please explain.

Comment: File > Invalidate caches > Invalidate and restart.